# Download images to a absolute path

Tags: python, scrapy

```
def parse_images(self,response):
    Name = response.meta['Name']
    album = response.meta['Album Name']
    os.makedirs(f'Master/{Name}/{album}',exist_ok=True)
    for ind,image in enumerate(response.xpath('//ul/li/a/img')):
        img = image.xpath('@srcset').extract_first().split(', ')[-1].split()[0] #image URL
        print(img)
        imageName = f'image_{ind+1}'+os.path.splitext(img)[1] #image_1.jpg
        path = os.path.join('Master',Name,album,imageName)
        abs_path = os.path.abspath(path) #Path where I want to download
```

How can I create a pipeline to store the image in the absolute path I created,I checked  [Downloading Item Images](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/images.html) but I can't find a way to change the storage place.

Note: I do prefer to stay with `scrapy` and not use `requests` to actually download the images

Comment: first you should set `IMAGES_STORE = "/absolute/path/to/Master"` and later use pipeline to rename to `{Name}/{album}/{imagename}` and finally it will download to absolute path `IMAGES_STORE/{Name}/{album}/{imagename}`

Comment: @furas can you please provide the pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example gets images from `http://books.toscrape.com/` and use `pipeline` to put in subfolders using first char of filename.

---

I settings I set path to `Master`

It can be relative

```
 'IMAGES_STORE': 'Master',
```

or absolute path

```
 'IMAGES_STORE': '/full/path/to/Master',
```

This folder has to exist before run code. If doesn't exists then `pipeline` will not create it and it will not download. But `pipeline` will create subfolders automatically so you will no need `makedirs()`.

---

In `parser` I add `name` and `album` to `item` so these values will be send to `pipeline`

def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

```
    #open_in_browser(response)  # to see url in web browser

    # download images and convert to JPG (even if it is already JPG)
    for url in response.css('img::attr(src)').extract():
        url = response.urljoin(url)
        image = url.rsplit('/')[-1] # get first char from image name
        yield {'image_urls': [url], 'name': 'books', 'album': image[0]}
```

---

In `pipeline` in `get_media_requests()` I get values from `item` and put in `meta` to send it to `file_path` which generates local path for file (in `IMAGES_STORE`).

```
def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    for image_url in item['image_urls']:
        # send `meta` to `file_path()`
        yield scrapy.Request(image_url, meta={'name': item['name'], 'album': item['album']})
```

---

In `pipeline` in `full_path()` I get values from `meta` and finally I create path `name/album/image.jpg`. Originally `pipeline` use `hashcode` as filename

```
def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
    # get `meta`
    name  = request.meta['name']
    album = request.meta['album']
    image = request.url.rsplit('/')[-1]
    #print('file_path:', request.url, request.meta, image)

    return '%s/%s/%s' % (name, album, image)
```

And this saves image in `IMAGES_STORE/name/album/image.jpg`

---

Minimal working example.

You can put all code in one file and run it as normal script - `python script.py` - without creating `scrapy` project. This way everyone can easily test this code.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
#from scrapy.commands.view import open_in_browser
#import json

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    #allowed_domains = []

    # see page created for scraping: http://toscrape.com/
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/'] #'http://quotes.toscrape.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        #open_in_browser(response)  # to see url in web browser

        # download images and convert to JPG (even if it is already JPG)
        for url in response.css('img::attr(src)').extract():
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            image = url.rsplit('/')[-1] # get first char from image name
            yield {'image_urls': [url], 'name': 'books', 'album': image[0]}


# --- pipelines ---

import os

# --- original code ---  # needed only if you use `image_guid`
#import hashlib        
#from scrapy.utils.python import to_bytes
# --- original code ---

class RenameImagePipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    '''Pipeline to change file names - to add folder name'''

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        # --- original code ---
        #for image_url in item['image_urls']:
        #    yield scrapy.Request(image_url)
        # --- original code ---

        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            # send `meta` to `file_path()`
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url, meta={'name': item['name'], 'album': item['album']})

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        # --- original code ---
        #image_guid = hashlib.sha1(to_bytes(request.url)).hexdigest()
        #return 'full/%s.jpg' % (image_guid,)
        # --- original code ---

        # get `meta`
        name  = request.meta['name']
        album = request.meta['album']
        image = request.url.rsplit('/')[-1]
        #image_guid = hashlib.sha1(to_bytes(request.url)).hexdigest()
        print('file_path:', request.url, request.meta, image) #, image_guid)

        #return '%s/%s/%s.jpg' % (name, album, image_guid)
        return '%s/%s/%s' % (name, album, image)

# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', #

    # download images to `IMAGES_STORE/full` (standard folder) and convert to JPG (even if it is already JPG)
    # it needs `yield {'image_urls': [url]}` in `parse()` and both ITEM_PIPELINES and IMAGES_STORE to work

    #'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1},  # used standard ImagePipeline (download to IMAGES_STORE/full)
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'__main__.RenameImagePipeline': 1},             # used Pipeline create in current file (needs __main___)
    #'IMAGES_STORE': '/full/path/to/valid/dir',  # this folder has to exist before downloading
    'IMAGES_STORE': 'Master',  # this folder has to exist before downloading
})

c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

---

**BTW:** Using

```
import scrapy
print(scrapy.__file__)
```

you can find source code and see how it looks in original `ImagePipeline`. In full example above I put some original code in comments.

On Linux I have

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scrapy/
```

and

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scrapy/pipelines/files.py
```

---

**BTW:** `ImagePipeline` compresses all images to `JPG` - event if you download `JPG`. If you want to keep original image then you may need `FilePipeline` instead of `ImagePipeline`. And `FILE_STORE` instead of `IMAGE_STORE`.

---

**BTW:** Sometimes is problem with `Pipeline` because it doesn't display error messages (`scrapy` catch errors and doesn't display) so it hard to recognize when there is mistake in code in `Pipeline`.

---

**EDIT:** The same example but with `FilesPipeline` (and `FILE_STORES` and `item['file_urls']`).

I put comments with phrase `"instead of"` to show differences.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
#from scrapy.commands.view import open_in_browser
#import json

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    #allowed_domains = []

    # see page created for scraping: http://toscrape.com/
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/'] #'http://quotes.toscrape.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        #open_in_browser(response)  # to see url in web browser

        # download all types of files (without converting images to JPG)
        for url in response.css('img::attr(src)').extract():
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            image = url.rsplit('/')[-1] # get first char from image name
            #yield {'image_urls': [url], 'name': 'books', 'album': image[0]}
            yield {'file_urls': [url], 'name': 'books', 'album': image[0]}  # <--- file_urls instead of image_urls

# --- pipelines ---

import os

#class RenameImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
class RenameFilesPipeline(FilesPipeline):  # <-- FilesPipeline instead of ImagesPipeline
    '''Pipeline to change file names - to add folder name'''

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        #for image_url in item['image_urls']:
        for image_url in item['file_urls']:   # <--- file_urls instead of image_urls
            # send `meta` to `file_path()`
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url, meta={'name': item['name'], 'album': item['album']})

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        # get `meta`
        name  = request.meta['name']
        album = request.meta['album']
        image = request.url.rsplit('/')[-1]
        print('file_path:', request.url, request.meta, image)

        return '%s/%s/%s' % (name, album, image)

# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', #

    # --- images ---

    # download images to `IMAGES_STORE/full` (standard folder) and convert to JPG (even if it is already JPG)
    # it needs `yield {'image_urls': [url]}` in `parse()` and both ITEM_PIPELINES and IMAGES_STORE to work

    #'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1},  # used standard ImagesPipeline (download to IMAGES_STORE/full)
    #'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'__main__.RenameImagesPipeline': 1}, 
    #'IMAGES_STORE': '/full/path/to/valid/dir',  # this folder has to exist before downloading

    # --- files ---

    # download files to `FILES_STORE/full` (standard folder) (without converting images)
    # it needs `yield {'file_urls': [url]}` in `parse()` and both ITEM_PIPELINES and FILES_STORE to work

    #'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1},  # used standard FilesPipeline (download to FILES_STORE/full)
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'__main__.RenameFilesPipeline': 1},  # <--- RenameFilesPipeline instead of RenameImagesPipeline
    'FILES_STORE': 'Master',  # this folder has to exist before downloading  # <--- FILES_STORE instead of IMAGES_STORE
})

c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: I added example with `FilesPipeline` and with comments which show differences.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is more than helpful